# Delete multiple store views programmatically

Tags: multistore, model, store-view, delete, array

I am trying to delete multiple store views using a php script that includes `app/Mage.php` in the root of my installation.

I am able to get the list of websites and store views but I need to somehow parse them into the `delete()` method as an array the loop over each `store_id` in order to delete the ones I no longer need.

Also, I need to find a way to filter the `store_id` so that I don't remove the default store view or admin.

Here is what I have so far:

```
/** Load Magento **/
umask(0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

/** Load webstes and stores */
echo "Website ID: " . Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() . "<br/>";
echo "Website Name: " . Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getName() . "<br/>";
echo "Store ID: " . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() . "<br/>";
echo "Store Name: ".Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(). "<br/>";
echo "Store code: ". Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()."<br/>";

/** @var ** $website loop */
foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
        $stores = $group->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            echo $store->getId() ." ".$store->getName()."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
/** ** End of script */
```

I'm haven't been able to find a way to call the `delete()` method foreach `store_id` using:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($stores);
$model->delete();
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use storeId instead of $stores

like

```
$model = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($store->getId());
$model->delete();
```

load function will load current store in for loop with **$store->getId()**

this is just pseudocode use should have to follow  just checkout with detail code in mage library

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you get following error `Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area` which will prevent deletion of stores. Add below code in script.

`Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);`

[Source](https://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/how-to-delete-magento-product-from-frontend-template-code-from-view-files/)